# Metodo não é reconhecido dentro do select linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

A consulta linq funciona perfeitamente, porém quando incluo o método GetQtdecPossible que retorna um inteiro, para obter a quantidade possivel e não precisar fazer outras consultas da erro. O que faço de errado?

```
 var fpcpAdd = (from fpp in contexto.FPP
                join fpc in contexto.FPC on fpp.fpId equals fpc.fpId
                join fpcp in contexto.FPCP on new { fpp.fppId, fpc.ecId }
                      equals new { fpcp.fppId, fpcp.ecId } into x
                               from d in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where (fpp.fpId == fpId &&
                       fpIds.Contains(fpp.fpId) &&
                       etIds.Contains(fpp.etId)) &&
                       ecIds.Contains(fpc.ecId) &&
                       d == null
                select new { fpp.fppId,
                             fpc.ecId, 
                             Qtdpossible = GetQtdecPossible(fpp.fppId)
                               }).Distinct().ToList();
```

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetQtdecPossible(System.Decimal)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: não dá porque em ao realizar a consulta o linq tenta transformar isso em uma query, e em tese seu método não é uma query, mas um código c#, saca?  alternativa: reestruturar sua query

Comment: Muito obrigado!